# Facebook Graph API returns empty data response for page events

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, facebook-graph-api

When making a Graph API call to `/{page-id}/events` using v2.12 the response comes back as 200 but with an empty data response.

Response:

`{
  "data": [
  ]
}`

Checking all the settings they appear to be correct, but I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious.

I'm an admin, I have a valid access token.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...apps currently accessing Events and Groups APIs will lose access
>   today

[Facebook Graph API does not return Page Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791977/facebook-graph-api-does-not-return-page-events)