# Facebook Graph API -> user/events returns empty array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Firstly, to explain the situation:

- my app has been approved by App Review for `user_events` (screenshot below)
- i am testing on the production app, with a real user account (testing with admin user returns false positives)
- calling `{user_id}/` works and returns the basic profile.
- calling `{user_id}/permissions` works and returns the permissions (inc `user_events`, screenshot below)
- calling `{user_id}/events` always 'works' but returns and empty array.

I have tried testing with 'me' instead of the logged in fb_user_id and get the same empty data result. If I test from my own admin testing account, the user_events data is always populated with data. I have tried with less/no parameters than the screenshot below, all work fine for test users but not for live users.

Many thanks for any help!

*screenshots:*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Testing with another user

My app is in development mode. You can also easily create and use [testing users, customize them to your needs and log in to the account](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users/), or you can add a real facebook user to your account and assign him the tester role.

[image]

I log in with Ellison Clinton and create an event

[image]

I can retrieve via api the `/events`

[image]

Then I switch the facebook app to production and delete the user from the test role

[image]

I can retrieve the user information

[image]

but I can not retrieve the previously created event

[image]

### Completing the authorization process

Maybe you did not complete the review process for `user_events`?

You can access [the data in development](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50608472/7295772), but not in production. I also did not complete the review process, but I can access the `user_events` data.

> "If your app is in dev mode you should be able to get page access tokens with any permission for anybody who has a role on your app. If you just want to manage posts on your own page or the pages of users who have roles on your app, you'll be able to do so in development mode without submitting for app review." - Response from Facebook Developer Support

You may need to perform the

- [Business
  Verification](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review#business-verification)
- [Individual Verification](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review#individual-verification)

also consider [filing a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/) and including the link here

### How to debug Facebook Graphql

The only possible scenario is that the token you are using does not include the `user_events` permission.

A request to `/users/events` with token missing the `user_events` permission will return status `200` and `data: []`, no error messages in the response.

I tested this scenario on the [Graphql Facebook Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and the request does not return an error message. A debug message is displayed in the `Api explorer`, but it is not explicitly included in the response.

[image]

I exported this request as curl and this is the result

```
~ $ curl -i -X GET  "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/10210855772523702/events?access_token=TOKEN"
HTTP/2 200 
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
facebook-api-version: v3.3
x-fb-debug: h1WInt+yxtkm/1isTGfG2cd9JX8HAx5R5A9U/QC4k2lRrJ5mrKYaInR2Mm6XQ5UOrdSquAgWKnYj2jiTw6fwLQ==

{"data":[]}
```

You can retrieve the debug info [passing the param `debug=all` in your `/users/events` request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/debugging) as in the `curl` example below:

```
~ $ curl -i -X GET  "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/10210855772523702/events?debug=all&access_token=TOKEN"
HTTP/2 200 
{"data":[],"__debug__":{"messages":[{"message":"The field 'events' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants the 'user_events' permission.","type":"warning"}]}}
```

My advice to you is to add the parameter `?debug=all` to your request and include the result of the response in your question, so that we can assist you troubleshooting.

Below are the other test I performed with the `Graphql Facebook Explorer` and I was able to retrieve the events.

---

**STEP 1. Head over to [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)**

[image]

**STEP 2. Generate a Token**

1. `get token -> get user access token` and add the `user_events` permission

**STEP 3. Run the queries**

Use the endpoint `/me?fields=id,name` to retrieve your user-id and then:

1. get `/{user-id}`
2. get `/{user-id}/permission`
3. get `/{user-id/events`

as you can see from the pictures below, `/events` returns `data: []`, while the `/permissions` endpoint includes the `user_events` permission.

My Facebook user did not join any event in the future. Creating an event and repeating the test returned some results.

The images below showcase my test cases

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, @Haroldo . I updated my answer. I believe that the token you are using has no `user_events` permission. In this case, the request will return status `200` and `data: []`. No error message is included in the `response`. To verify this scenario you can test the request in the [facebook graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) or [enable debug in your request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/debugging) to provide us more info. I remain available to you. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks @Fabrizio - I have tried doing this with curl and debug all as suggested but the results are the same. Both my admin user and clean fb account return the desired /permissions for their respective access_tokens, but the clean account returns data=[] for /events (there are lots of events associated with this account) while the admin account returns a full data set.

debug only gives me: 
__debug__":{"messages":[{"link":"https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/apps\/versions\/","message":"No API version was specified. This request defaulted to version v2.9.","type":"warning"}]}}

Comment: @Haroldo I tested your full query and it works also with your parameters. Currently I have no idea why it does not work for you in production and I believe that [you should contact facebook, file a bug and share with us the information](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/) so that we can better help you. Thanks and sorry

Comment: does your code work for a user that is not a developer/tester of the app?

Comment: @Haroldo I updated my post as by you requested. STEP 1) I created a new user and added it as test user to the facebook.developers console, I can retrieve his events STEP 2) I moved to production my app, I updated my privacy policy and removed the user as test. I can not retrieve the events.
Maybe you need to **Complete the authorization process** as explained in my post? Thanks. I don't think that the issue is related to the query itself, but your settings in the developers console restricting data usage

Comment: @Haroldo thanks. I need the points. Can I further assist you? Fabrizio

Answer (score -3):

Did you "sign in" your live user to your app, and after that choose this user to access to their token? Only after that, you can access the event of this user and etc. in case if that user gives permission for you.

1) You have to register in your app what kind of accessors your app will approve by Facebook for your app.

2) User has to be logged in to your app. (Choose token of your user in droplist like on the photo)

3) The user that is logged into your app must have open permission on their events, posts, etc.

[Choose a user here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7KZ0.png)