# Graph API doesn't return Page Events with a valid Page Access Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

Due to many Facebook's access policies changes, the question may seem duplicated, but it's not.

My application followed all facebook approval process, and at the moment it has been approved by the "App Review" to get "manage_pages" permission. This allows to obtain a "Page Access Token" which grants the access to the page events, wherever the user is Guest or Host. ([Facebook manage_pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-manage_pages))

**After switching from Development to Live mode**, the */page/events* endpoint returns an empty object, with all my granted users, with a valid longlive page access token.

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Has anyone ever encountered this issue?
Thanks.

---

Past references about this:

[Facebook Graph API does not return Page Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791977/facebook-graph-api-does-not-return-page-events)

[How can I get the events for a Facebook page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825680/how-can-i-get-the-events-for-a-facebook-page)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/: _“This is a restricted edge. You cannot request access at this time.”_

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event: _“Page Event access is restricted to whitelisted partners at this time.”_